# Delete from MS SQL using Split

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

I'm using

```
       INSERT INTO [dbo].[ADMIN_Publications_email]
       ([email]
       ,[pmid]
       )
      SELECT @email, CAST(Item AS NVARCHAR(10)) 
     FROM  dbo.Split(@PMID_List, ',')
```

The Split is a pretty standard function to split a string.  The Insert works fine but I need a way to Delete a record if it is already added.  This way if the same process it done over and over again I don't get a whole bunch of duplicate records.  How can I Deleted based upon the email address and a value in the PMID_list.  I can't delete all because they could be added a different way.  I need something like

```
     DELETE FROM [dbo].[ADMIN_Publications_email]
WHERE (email = @Email) AND IN dbo.Split(@PMID_LIST)
```

Where the split is in the where clause.

Comment: Instead of deleting everything up front, you could also consider just skipping already inserted data by adding a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` to your `INSERT` query. (This works only if you know the data is stable, of course.)

Comment: You broke my heart. I thought you were going to normalize your data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50498610/saving-data-in-a-sql-server-2016-database-for-a-specfic-report

Answer (score 1):

you can use this.

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[ADMIN_Publications_email]
WHERE (email = @Email) AND [pmid] IN (SELECT CAST(Item AS NVARCHAR(10)) FROM dbo.Split(@PMID_LIST))
```

Comment: I wonder how efficient this is compared to the NOT EXISTS method listed below?  I'm leaning to just deleting them all like this.

Comment: I just fixed the delete query. it is hard to say the best method without try but you are comparing with static values and using IN would be better. EXISTS works better with tables. Instead of delete after insert, i recommend not insert them.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend inserting and deleting. Just use

```
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[ADMIN_Publications_email]
       ([email]
       ,[pmid]
       )
      SELECT @email, CAST(Item AS NVARCHAR(10)) 
     FROM  dbo.Split(@PMID_List, ',')  
     WHERE NOT EXISTS 
     (
        select 1 from [dbo].[ADMIN_Publications_email] where [email]=@email and [pmid]=CAST(Item AS NVARCHAR(10)) 
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[ADMIN_Publications_email] WHERE pmid IN (SELECT Item FROM  @PMID_LIST) OR email = @Email
```

Comment: Please add a better explanation.